# Buying readymade healthy food

Tags: weight-loss, food, meal-plan

I know these two terms don't go well together but I need advice on how to pick healthy foods that I can simply buy and eat. I hate cooking and I live in a temporary accomodation where the kitchen is not that great. I eat only 2 meals a day (breakfast and dinner) with a snack at noon. I train 3 times a week and my training usually consists of bar training+300abs+30min cardio.

Comment: Chances are this'll be closed as it's not really on topic for this site. BUT, which country are you in? Giving you recommendations of what to buy in UK supermarkets won't help if you're based in Sri Lanka.

Comment: I am based in uk

Comment: There is no generally healthy food. There is eating what you need and there is not eating what you need. People believe in all kinds of esoteric stuff when it comes to food, our ancestors believed that if we eat an animal, it becomes part of us and we gain its attributes. People haven't gotten that much more educated since. Whenever someone claims a food is healthy, the person doesn't know what he's talking about. A well-balanced diet is what you should aim for, not "healthy food"

Answer (score 1):

What are your dietary restrictions (vegetarian, pescatarian, vegan etc.)? What appliances do you have? Here are some suggestions:

For breakfast:

- Protein powder - this is a versatile ingredient and can be added into shakes/oats etc.
- Egg beaters (egg whites in a carton you can just pour into a pan and cook). They might not have these in the UK under the same name but there should be similar items.
- Oatmeal (is it porridge in the UK?)- just put oats in a bowl with some water and microwave for quick breakfast. Add toppings as desired. You can also mix in protein powder.
- If you have a blender, just buy a bunch of bananas/strawberries/spinach (or other desired fruits within caloric intake requirements) and freeze them. Add them into your blender with milk/water/almond milk etc along with protein powder if you desire.
- If your calories allow it, everything bagels are calorie dense and relatively distributed with macronutrients which is a great on the go breakfast item.

For dinner:

- Buy whole rotisserie chicken from your supermarket and just portion that and eat it throughout the week.
- Minute rice - literally rice you can crush and microwave for a minute for a rice meal. It's cheaper honestly to buy a rice cooker and just cook your own rice but to each his own.
- Vegetable packs you can just throw in the microwave to eat along with rice/chicken.
- You can also just wash potatoes, poke holes and microwave them with a damp paper towel over them.
- Protein powder shakes. I don't like using protein powder as a main meal but as a supplement when i'm not getting enough protein in. Throw in frozen spinach for fiber and or frozen bananas for creamy substance.

Comment: Hey. Im lactose intolerant ... And a microwave.

Comment: Substitute almond milk or water for milk. Use pea protein instead. What about a microwave?

Comment: Egg beaters and known as liquid egg whites in the UK, and are, unfortunately, quite hard to find (though you can order them from various sites like MyProtein). Oatmeal is sometimes called porridge, sometimes just oats, I think oatmeal tends to be a finer grind than porridge oats over here :)

Answer (score 0):

Yogurt, eggs, things like nuts in bags/containers, oatmeal/cream of wheat, etc (simple and you don't need to quote on quote cook it), nutrition bars, etc. As you can see my answer is going be things you probably already know. The reality is the healthy packaged foods that are ready to eat are very simple and not much too them, if you are looking to eat healthy it isn't wise to rely on ready to eat food. I don't like cooking either but you can easily cook the most basic foods, pre done meat, eggs, rice, etc crappy kitchen or not.

Usually pre-made meals including ones that are advertised as healthy aren't, they usually are high in salt or other such things. If you really hate cooking that much stick to the basics, easy to cook meat, rice, eggs, oatmeal, yogurt, fruits vegetables. Pasta is also incredibly easy. If you want to just throw stuff in the microwave or oven to heat up and eat you aren't in much luck.

Also why two meals in a day? Eating smaller but more meals throughout the day speeds up metabolism significantly compared to the normal three meals and you are even below that at two.

Comment: @Unbesiegt if you have a differing opinion, write it as an answer. Don't make wild claims in aa comment.

Comment: Eating smaller, more frequent meals does not speed up metabolism: https://jissn.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1550-2783-8-4